# Como usar o list quando não sabe o objeto que irá ser retornado?

Tags: c#, asp

Eu tenho um banco de dados Oracle e preciso popular um *gridView*. Estou fazendo com `var`, pois não sei o tipo que irá ser retornado. Tem como fazer uma lista em `var`, exemplo `list<var>`, e depois jogar no *grid*?

```
gridview1.datasource = lista var
grindview1.dataBird():

foreach (var nota in info)
{
    var prod = bd.PRODUTOes.Where(p => p.NOTA_FISCAL.Any(n => n.ID == nota.ID));
}
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro na sua pergunta? Você tem uma grid na tela que pode ser uma lista de vários objetos e precisa que isso seja dinamico, é isso?

Comment: Como não sabe o tipo a ser retornado? Será sempre um `IEnumerable<T>`, sendo `T` o tipo de `PRODUTOes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("nome");
dt.Columns.Add("VALOR_UNIT");

foreach(var nota in info)
{
   var prod = bd.PRODUTOes.Where(p => p.NOTA_FISCAL.Any(n => n.ID == nota.ID)).ToList();


   foreach(PRODUTO detalheProduto in prod)
   {
      dt.Rows.Add(detalheProduto.NOME, detalheProduto.VALOR_UNIT.ToString());
   }

}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```